# VBA Range find in 1 column to Show/Hide another column

Tags: excel, vba, find, range

This one has driven me mad so hopefully one of you can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

All I want to do is if any cell in column I contains the value "Y" then column J gets hidden. If you then delete the Y from any cell then column J appears again.

Here's my code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("I:I")
Set cell = rng.Find(What:="Y")
If cell Is Nothing Then
        Columns("J").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Else
        Columns("J").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Basically the code does absolutely nothing. Which annoys me more than getting an error, because I have no clue what I've done wrong.

Comment: Where is this code? Attached to the worksheet?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim cell As Range

Columns("I:I").Select
Set cell = Selection.Find(What:="Y", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If cell Is Nothing Then
    Columns("J").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Else
    Columns("J").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is something that works:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim c       As Range

    If Target.Column = 9 Then
        With Range("I:I")
            Set c = .Find("Y")
            If Not c Is Nothing Then
                Columns("J").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Else
                Columns("J").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            End If
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

- In order to make sure that it works, put your code in the corresponding sheet,not in the module
- Make sure that macros are enabled

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can keep this VBA really simple if you have a cell in your workbook which tests if there are any `Y` in column `I`. I put the following into cell `A1`

```
=COUNTIF(I:I,"Y")
```

I advise putting this on the worksheet because Excel is smart and will perform this calculation quicker than VBA - it also gives you some sight of what's going on.

We can now use the value of `A1` to determine whether to hide column J in the macro

---

Firstly, it's probably a good idea to test if column `J` is in the correct state when you open the workbook so put the following code into the `ThisWorkbook` module. *This code is optional*

```
Sub Workbook_Open()
    With Me.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        If .Range("A1").Value > 0 Then
            .Range("J:J").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Else:
            .Range("J:J").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Then to monitor any changes to values in column `I`, place the following code into your worksheet module

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("I:I")) Is Nothing Then
        If Me.Range("A1") > 0 Then
            Me.Range("J:J").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Else
            Me.Range("J:J").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Note: this code is not designed for the user changing multiple cells at once, which shouldn't be a problem if you intend to use it as described. If you wish to paste over multiple cells (for example) at a time, then this will need to be adapted slightly.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Columns("J").EntireColumn.Hidden = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Columns("I"),"Y") >0
End Sub
```

Or

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns("I")) Is Nothing Then Columns("J").EntireColumn.Hidden = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Columns("I"),"Y") >0
End Sub
```